# Table of Contents - section numbers and section headers too close

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, sv-classes

I'm using Springers [svmult](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/download?SGWID=0-40465-0-0-0) templated for a book with editor. There is a problem with the TableOfContents (ToC):

When the section number only includes digits 1-9, everything looks ok, e.g.

1. Header

1.1 Subheader

1.2.9 SubSubheader

but when section count goes past 10, the header text and the section number are way too close in the ToC, they even start to overlap. This looks ugly (worse than here):

1. Header

1.10Subheader

1.3.10SubSubheader

12.2.3SubSubheader

What follows is the definition of `\tableofcontents` in `svmult.cls`. I only understand it halfway, and thats not enough in this case. Where would I need to fix the problem, so that there always is enough space between section number and section header in the ToC?

```
\def\tableofcontents{\chapter*{\contentsname\markboth{{\contentsname}}%
                                                    {{\contentsname}}}
 \def\authcount##1{\setcounter{auco}{##1}\setcounter{@auth}{1}}
 \def\lastand{\ifnum\value{auco}=2\relax
                 \unskip{} \andname\
              \else
                 \unskip \lastandname\
              \fi}%
 \def\and{\stepcounter{@auth}\relax
          \ifnum\value{@auth}=\value{auco}%
             \lastand
          \else
             \unskip,
          \fi}%
 \@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\def\l@part#1#2{\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}%
   \addvspace{2em \@plus\p@}%
   \begingroup
     \parindent \z@
     \rightskip \z@ \@plus 5em
     \hrule\vskip5\p@
     \bfseries\boldmath
     \leavevmode
     #1\par
     \vskip5\p@
     \hrule
     \vskip\p@
     \nobreak
   \endgroup}

\def\@dotsep{2}

\def\addnumcontentsmark#1#2#3{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{\protect\numberline
                                    {\thechapter}#3}{\thepage}}}
\def\addcontentsmark#1#2#3{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
\def\addcontentsmarkwop#1#2#3{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{0}}}

\def\@adcmk[#1]{\ifcase #1 \or
\def\@gtempa{\addnumcontentsmark}%
  \or    \def\@gtempa{\addcontentsmark}%
  \or    \def\@gtempa{\addcontentsmarkwop}%
  \fi\@gtempa{toc}{chapter}}
\def\addtocmark{\@ifnextchar[{\@adcmk}{\@adcmk[3]}}

\def\l@chapter#1#2{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
 \addvspace{1.0em \@plus \p@}
 \@tempdima \tocchpnum \begingroup
 \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@tocrmarg
 \advance\rightskip by \z@ \@plus 2cm
 \parfillskip -\rightskip \pretolerance=10000
 \leavevmode \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip
 {\bfseries\boldmath#1}\ifx0#2\hfil\null
 \else
      \nobreak
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern
      \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}%
 \fi\par
 \penalty\@highpenalty \endgroup}

\newcommand{\tocauthorstyle}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\toctitlestyle}{\bfseries}

\def\l@title#1#2{\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
 \addvspace{8\p@ \@plus \p@}
 \@tempdima \z@
 \tocchpnum \z@ \calctocindent
 \begingroup
 \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@tocrmarg
 \advance\rightskip by \z@ \@plus 2cm
 \pretolerance=10000
%\parfillskip -\@tocrmarg
 \leavevmode \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip
 {\toctitlestyle#1}%\nobreak
%\leaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu.\mkern
%\@dotsep mu$}\hfill
%\nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
 \par
 \penalty\@highpenalty \endgroup}

\newcommand{\tocaftauthskip}{\z@}
\def\l@author#1#2{%\addpenalty{\@highpenalty}
 \@tempdima \z@
 \begingroup
 \pretolerance=10000
 \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@tocrmarg
 \advance\rightskip by \z@ \@plus 2cm
 \parfillskip -\@tocrmarg
 \leavevmode \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip
 {\tocauthorstyle#1}\nobreak
 \leaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu.\mkern
 \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
 \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
 \penalty\@highpenalty
 \addvspace{\tocaftauthskip}\endgroup}

\newdimen\tocchpnum
\newdimen\tocsecnum
\newdimen\tocsectotal
\newdimen\tocsubsecnum
\newdimen\tocsubsectotal
\newdimen\tocsubsubsecnum
\newdimen\tocsubsubsectotal
\newdimen\tocparanum

\newdimen\tocparatotal
\newdimen\tocsubparanum
\tocchpnum=\z@            % no chapter numbers
\tocsecnum=18\p@          % section 88. plus 2.222pt
\tocsubsecnum=23\p@       % subsection 88.8 plus 2.222pt
\tocsubsubsecnum=27\p@    % subsubsection 88.8.8 plus 1.444pt
\tocparanum=35\p@         % paragraph 88.8.8.8 plus 1.666pt
\tocsubparanum=43\p@      % subparagraph 88.8.8.8.8 plus 1.888pt
\def\calctocindent{%
\tocsectotal=\tocchpnum
\advance\tocsectotal by\tocsecnum
\tocsubsectotal=\tocsectotal
\advance\tocsubsectotal by\tocsubsecnum
\tocsubsubsectotal=\tocsubsectotal
\advance\tocsubsubsectotal by\tocsubsubsecnum
\tocparatotal=\tocsubsubsectotal
\advance\tocparatotal by\tocparanum}
\calctocindent

\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \advance\rightskip by \z@ \@plus 2cm
               \parfillskip -\rightskip \pretolerance=10000
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
%
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{\tocchpnum}{\tocsecnum}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{\tocsectotal}{\tocsubsecnum}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{\tocsubsectotal}{\tocsubsubsecnum}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{\tocsubsubsectotal}{\tocparanum}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{\tocparatotal}{\tocsubparanum}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class controls the space reserved for the sectional number using the following lengths:

- `\tocsecnum` for sections.
- `\tocsubsecnum` for subsections.
- `\tocsubsubsecnum` for subsubsections.
- `\tocparanum` for paragraphs.
- `\tocsubparanum` for subparagraphs.

you can then simply add some value to the required length; for example:

```
\addtolength\tocsubsubsecnum{2ex}
```

and then invoke

```
\calctocindent
```

so that the lengths for lower sectional unit entries can be recalculated.