# Numbers too close to figure captions in List of Figures, can this be fixed without changing the class?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, indentation

On my List of Figures page, my figures go up to 4 digits, such as Figure 13.14.

This causes the figure list to be right up against the text, such as:

```
13.9 My figure
13.10My next figure
```

I need to change the width reserved for these numbers. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68389/table-of-contents-section-numbers-and-section-headers-too-close), but it seemed to only pertain to being able to change the class itself. I'd rather not screw around with the class file if I can at all help it.

Is there something I can do in my preamble to fix this problem?

Comment: If your document class is (based on)  one of the standard ones, add to the preamble `\makeatletter\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.5em}{3em}}\makeatother` Change the lengths according to your needs.

Comment: Sadly, this did not appear to work for me. I don't think the List of Figures deviates from a standard one (it's the ucthesis style which is fairly close to the standard ones), but nothing happened when this was added.

Comment: Sorry: it should have been `\renewcommand` or `\def`; see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ucthesis.cls` uses `\@dottedtocline` to format the entries in the Lot and LoF and, in partular, it defines

```
\def\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

so figure entries in the LoF are indented by `1.5em` and the width reserved to typeset the figure number is `2.3em`. To add a little more space, change `2.3em` to a higher value in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{ucthesis}

\makeatletter
\def\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\setcounter{chapter}{10}% just for the example
\chapter{Test}
\setcounter{figure}{10}% just for the example
\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{A test figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\caption{Another test figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Not only does this work, but the values you chose are excellent. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  If you have a few moments, could you explain why the command works or provide a link to some documentation that explains it.  thanks!