# In List of Figures, "Figure" and "colon" are disappeared when changing gap between Figure Numbers and Caption

Tags: table-of-contents

I have found the question [Numbers too close to figure captions in List of Figures, can this be fixed without changing the class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117088/numbers-too-close-to-figure-captions-in-list-of-figures-can-this-be-fixed-witho) very helpful to add some spacing in List-of-figure in a Report document. But one thing I want to ask that while doing this, now in generated LOF the the word "Figure" is missing and also the dot is replaces the colon ":"
Can anyone please suggest how I can fix these two things (**Figure** X.XX **:**) in my LOF while maintaining the same spacing.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}                           

    \titlecontents
    {chapter}
    [0.5in]
    {\addvspace{1pc} \normalfont \filright}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{0.2in}}
    {\hspace{-0.5in}}
    {\titlerule*[4pt]{.} \contentspage}                         
    [\addvspace{2pt}]                                                               

    \titlecontents
    {section}                               
    [0.8in]                                     
    {\normalfont \filright}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0.3in}}
    {}                                                                                  
    {\titlerule*[4pt]{.} \contentspage}                         
    []                                                                                          

\titlecontents
    {subsection}                                                                        
    [1.3in]                                                                                 
    {\normalfont \filright}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0.5in}}
    {}                                                                                          
    {\titlerule*[4pt]{.} \contentspage}                         
    []  

\titlecontents
    {subsubsection}                                                                     
    [1.5in]                                                                                 
    {\normalfont \slshape \filright}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0.7in}}
    {}                                                                                          
    {\titlerule*[4pt]{.} \contentspage}                         
    []  

\titlecontents
    {table}                                                                                 
    [0.8in]                                                                                 
    {\normalfont \filright}
    {\contentslabel[Table \thecontentslabel :~]{0.8in}}
    {}                                                                                          
    {\titlerule*[4pt]{.} \contentspage}                         
    []                                                                                          
\titlecontents
    {figure}                                                                                
    [0.8in]                                                                                 
    {\normalfont \filright}
    {\contentslabel[Figure \thecontentslabel : \hspace{0.5in}]{0.8in}}
    {}                                                                                          
    {\titlerule*[4pt]{.} \contentspage}                         
    []                                                                                          

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}                                         
\titleformat
    {\chapter}                                                                          
    [display]                                                                               
    {\normalfont \centering}                                                
    {CHAPTER \thechapter}                                                       
    {0.2in}                                                                                 
    {}[]                                                                                        
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.7in}{0.5in}[0pt]    
\titleformat
    {\section}                                                                          
    [hang]                                                                                  
    {\normalfont \bfseries}                                                 
    {\thesection}                                                                       
    {0.1in}                                                                                 
    {}[]                                                                                        
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{36pt}{6pt}[0pt]           
\titleformat
    {\subsection}                                                                       
    [hang]
    {\normalfont \bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}                                                                
    {0.1in}
    {}[]

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{36pt}{6pt}[0pt]            
\titleformat
    {\subsubsection}                                                                        
    [hang]
    {\normalfont \slshape}
    {\thesubsubsection}                                                             
    {0.2in}
    {}[]


 \makeatletter
 \def \l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}} 
 \makeatother


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}     
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}           
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\sloppy 
\clearpage \pagenumbering{roman}                                    
\include{FrontMatter/myTitle}                                           

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{1pc} \protect\hspace{-0.28in}
\protect\mbox{CHAPTERS} \par}                                           
\clearpage \newgeometry{top=0.5in} \singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\include{FrontMatter/abbreviations}
\include{FrontMatter/symbols}

\restoregeometry
\clearpage \pagenumbering{arabic}                                   
\include{MainMatter/1/introduction}                                         

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: "Figure" never appears in the list of figures (redundant).  So you want to add it?

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, it is required, as mentioned in my university thesis guideline

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I have added the preamble

Comment: There are some packages that miss the closing brace. Commenting out those, the behaviour cannot be reproduced. You are using package `tocloft` to deal with the spacing in the LOF. You did not specify which spacing should be changed explicitely. Please provide a minimal working example (the above is a madness of code) and specify the question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe you know why that line was introduced and what it was supposed to solve. I don't know which spacing should be corrected.